# How to make a new disk usable on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ubuntu-server

I've set up a remote ubuntu server back in the day on a 5GB drive from the 100GB that my host provided just to test. Time flew by and turns out that I'm still using the test environment and now I need more space. My host allows me to attach a new empty disk to the remote machine, with any size I want (available from the remaining 95GB). But that's all I can do from the web interface: I do not have the option to manage the partition table from it. So I've attached a 20GB drive to the remote machine.

```
user@snf-217047:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/vda: 5368 MB, 5368709120 bytes
149 heads, 8 sectors/track, 8796 cylinders, total 10485760 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000619d1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048    10483711     5240832   83  Linux

Disk /dev/vdb: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
16 heads, 63 sectors/track, 41610 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/vdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

What I want to know is what do I do now to add the 20GB to my system. I don't wanna ask "How do I resize home or how do I create a new partition" because I want see my options. So the question is **how do I make the 20GB disk usable in my system?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a multi-step process.

**First,** you need to *identify* the device node of the disk in question. There are a few ways to do that, and you have done it through `fdisk -l`; in your case, the device node for the new disk is /dev/vdb (that is the device node of the only detected disk that does not contain a valid partition table). You may **also** want to identify directories which take up a large amount of space and which are easy to move to other partitions; good candidates depending on how the system is being used might be /home, /opt, /srv and subdirectories under /var. **Do not** move files or directories which the system needs to boot. *Always* leave /bin, /boot, /dev, /etc, /lib*, /proc, /run, /sbin and /sys alone, unless you know *exactly* what you are doing, why, and what consequences it will have. Be careful about /usr.

**Second,** you need to *partition* the disk. Use `fdisk` or a similar utility to do that; `fdisk /dev/vdb` should get you started. Create one or more partitions on it, depending on your intended usage. If you need something a bit more user-friendly, try `cfdisk` (you may need to install that separately first).

**Third,** you need to create *file systems* (this is called "formatting" in the Microsoft world) on each of the partitions you created. It is possible that you need to reboot after partitioning; since the consequences of a mismatch can be severe, I prefer doing so as a matter of routine, just to make sure that all system components have the same view of the partition table. You normally create file systems using the `mkfs.*` family of tools, but exceptions may exist (and some have aliases, like mkfs.ext2 which is often aliased to mke2fs). For example, if you want to create an ext4 file system on /dev/vdb2, you'd run something like `mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdb2`. Read the relevant man page first for details on options that you may find useful. *Make absolutely sure that you are using the correct device node here; complacency kills.*

**Fourth,** you need to tell the system to mount the file systems at whatever mount point you are interested in. (This is not generally needed in the Microsoft world, because partitions are assigned drive letters by default, and you only need to configure anything if you want to change that assignment.) Other *nixes may be different, but on Linux this is configured through /etc/fstab, which has the format `device mountpoint fstype options dump pass`. `dump` and `pass` are often left at `0`, `options` can often be left at `defaults` with the exception of the root file system, and the others depend on your setup. For example, to mount the ext4 file system on /dev/vdb3 on the mountpoint /srv/www, you'd add a line like:

```
/dev/vdb3 /srv/www ext4 defaults 0 0
```

The way to remember the order is "what where how?".

**Do not** add multiple entries for the same device node or mountpoint. It might not even work (I did the mistake once of mounting two different file systems at `/`, which caused all kinds of confusion and wasn't entirely easy to realize what was going on despite the fact that I have some 15 years of experience with different Linux distributions), and it will *not* extend the file system across the multiple devices.

I always recommend using persistent device identifiers *particularly* in /etc/fstab and other similar configuration points. Look in /dev/disk/by-* for symlinks that should come in handy. The advantage of especially those in /dev/disk/by-id is that they remain the same even if the disk is moved or the detection order changes (this can happen very easily in large setups!).

**Fifth,** make sure the mount point directory exists and is empty (`ls -A` is your friend here). (It will probably work even if the directory is not empty, but you *will* get confused.)

**Sixth,** you may want to move any existing files (under the relevant directory on the old file system) to the new partition. To do that, mount the file system on the new partition at some temporary location (/mnt is commonly used for such purposes), move all the files, then unmount the new file system from its temporary mount point. *Make sure* to stop any relevant services before you do this. For example, to migrate everything in /srv to the new file system at /dev/vdb2, try something like:

```
# shopt -s dotglob
# cd /srv
# mount /dev/vdb2 /mnt
# mv ./* /mnt
# umount /mnt
```

**Seventh,** do a `mount -a` to mount all file systems listed in /etc/fstab, followed by `mount` or `df` to verify that the new file systems get mounted as expected. (They should be listed in the output, and `df` should report them as essentially empty unless you moved files onto them like in step 6 above.) After that everything should be fine and you can start using those file systems, but you may want to reboot the system again and verify that the file systems are mounted on boot just to be sure. At this point you may also want to use `chmod` to set appropriate permissions on the file systems' root directories; for example `chmod 775 /srv/www`.

Comment: Alright so If I add "/" as the mountpoint in the 4th step that would not be clever I assume? Supposing that I want to extend the space of all the folders in /dev/vda1 that is.

Comment: @Crone No, you cannot add a second file system with the same mountpoint as an existing one in such a way. (I did that once *by mistake*, and it caused all kinds of confusion, so if you are not familiar with how this works -- which I presume is why you asked the question in the first place -- then *just make sure that you don't do that*.) You *will* however get the full space on the new file system available under the mount point you mount the new file system on, so if you make one large partition and mount that at /srv, you'll have 20 GB (+/- rounding error and metadata) available at /srv.